# video tag not display video

Tags: html, video-streaming, html5-video, flash

I have a video to be displayed using  tag but it does not work and gives this error on browser "no video supported format and mime type".

I have latest firefox version and also have installed flash player. While YouTube videos works fine.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Please provide your HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on where the video is sourced from. If it's on your computer or server, try opening it using Firefox to check for errors in the video itself. If it's from a website, make sure that your Internet and the video uploaded are fine. If both are proper, then there's probably an error in the code. Post that.

Comment: I will edit with the code once I reach home. But the same code works fine on other PCs.